# Does MS-specific volatile prevent hardware instructions reordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, volatile, memory-fences

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx):

> **Microsoft Specific**
>
> When the /volatile:ms compiler option is used—by default when
>   architectures other than ARM are targeted—the compiler generates extra
>   code to maintain ordering among references to volatile objects in
>   addition to maintaining ordering to references to other global
>   objects.In particular:
>
> - A write to a volatile object (also known as volatile write) has    Release semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object
>     that occurs before a write to a volatile object in the instruction
>     sequence will occur before that volatile write in the compiled
>     binary.
> - A read of a volatile object (also known as volatile read) has Acquire semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object
>     that occurs after a read of volatile memory in the instruction
>     sequence will occur after that volatile read in the compiled binary.
>
> This enables volatile objects to be used for memory locks and releases
>   in multithreaded applications.

It surely guarantees that `volatile` prevents compiler from doing compile-time instructions reordering (because it explicitly states that the instruction 
sequence will be the same **in the compiled binary**).

But as we all know, there's also such thing like hardware reordering (like CPU being able to reorder instructions on their own will). Does `volatile` prevents it as well? I know that synchronization primitives (such as mutexes) do, but what about MS-specific `volatile`?

Comment: By "architectures other than ARM", MS probably means x86 and x64. On x86 and x64, loads are not reordered with other loads. And stores are not ordered with other stores. (with some exceptions such as non-temporal stores) IOW, as long as the compiler doesn't reorder anything, neither will the processor. It seems that `/volatile` for MS is trying to provide the functionality of `std::atomic` which didn't exist until C++11.

Comment: Furthermore, they say "has Release semantics", so the documentation certainly *claims* `volatile` prevents CPU reordering.

Comment: @Mysticial "It seems that /volatile for MS is trying to provide the functionality of std::atomic" -- no, it doesn't. For example, it isn't guaranteed that read and write operations to `volatile` variables are atomic. In fact, they are -- because x86 guarantees atomicity of read and write operations for 1-byte variables, but it isn't guaranteed in MSDN by `volatile`

Comment: @FrozenHeart Sorry, I should've clarified a bit. It's trying to provide the functionality of `std::memory_order_xxx` which `std::atomic` uses. Although acquire/release semantics for something that isn't atomic seems pretty uh... flaky.

Comment: @Mysticial Well, yes, it surely does. But are you sure about hardware reordering? If so, why didn't you write an answer to my question?

Comment: Why not just use the standard constructs where you *know* what the guarantees are and stop fiddling with platform specific gunk? Your code will be cleaner, more portable and easier to understand by your fellow developers.

Comment: Assuming that your fellow developers are not more familiar with the Microsoft-specific extensions than they are with the relatively-new standard-library additions. :-) This is certainly true in my experience. The visceral reaction on Stack Overflow to anything that isn't sufficiently "portable" gets tiring. x86 Windows applications are never going to be "portable", so you just use the right tools for the job that produce sensible, understandable code.

Comment: @Cody: But, read between the lines.  Microsoft is continuing to support this performance-killing version of `volatile` *for backward compatibility*.  If you find that it doesn't operate as you expect in the presence of new features such as lambdas, when you file the bug report you're quite possibly going to hear "You're writing new code, the bug doesn't affect existing code, and we already told you to use the mode `/volatile:iso` in new code"

Comment: @ben That's great assuming you are writing a new application from the ground up. What do you do with existing code bases? You can't just start writing the new bits using ISO-standard constructs and flip the `/volatile:iso` switch, because then it may break the old code. The two options don't mix well. As such, I rather doubt you're going to hear that response. Although I don't know, Microsoft's attitude has been surprising me a lot recently.

Comment: @CodyGray: I haven't personally tried linking between compilation units using the two different settings, but I can't see anything that would "not mix well".  So the answer to existing code is that you can write new code using the new setting, and use the linker to combine it with the old code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSDN docs on the MS-specific volatile behavior go all the way back to VS2003. So it's been around for a while—long before the existence of `std::atomic` in C++11.

So MS-specific volatile seems to be the way that one achieved acquire/release semantics in the old days. But now it is basically obsolete and they left a footnote nudging you away from MS-volatile in favor `std::atomic` and `/volatile:iso` for inter-thread communication.

---

As for why they exclude ARM, Microsoft didn't pick up ARM until relatively recently. Other than ARM, they support x86, x64, and Itanium (which is dead).

On x86 and x64, most loads and stores already have acquire/release semantics (with exceptions such as non-temporal stores). So as long as the compiler doesn't reorder anything, the processor won't either<sup>*</sup> and will therefore preserve the acquire/release semantics. The `/volatile:ms` flag tells the compiler not to reorder anything so that acquire/release semantics can be achieved on x86 and x64.

Since Microsoft's ARM support is relatively new, and MS-specific volatile (`/volatile:ms`) is outdated in favor of `std::atomic`, they probably decided to abandon the classic volatile semantics rather than updating them to work on ARM as well (which would probably mean adding memory barriers everywhere, given the lack of hardware support).

<sub>*The processor will still do whatever reordering it wants, but it will preserve the acquire/release semantics of the program since that's required by x86/x64. (minus the exceptional cases like nt-stores or clflush) How it does this without violating memory-ordering is a different topic.</sub>

Comment: The `ms-volatile` semantics make it possible to guarantee ordering with respect to objects that are accessible via "ordinary" pointers.  If I fill a buffer with data using non-qualified pointers, and then store its address to a `volatile * volatile`, wait for that pointer to be cleared, and then do something else with the buffer using non-qualified pointers, the first set of writes will be issued before the `volatile` store, and the second set of writes will not be issued until after the pointer has been cleared.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve similar semantics using atomics without requiring that the code which writes the buffer uses atomic-qualified pointers to do so?

Comment: @supercat Since the pointer itself is the synchronization variable, make the pointer `std::atomic`. Once you're finished writing the first time, you set the pointer with a store-release. While you waiting, you then do load-acquires on the pointer until it is cleared. Then you can do the 2nd set of writes. The load-acquire will prevent the 2nd set of writes from being moved before the load, thus the 2nd set of writes can only happen after the pointer is cleared.

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood your comment. Did you mean *without* making the pointer itself atomic? I'm not sure that's possible without using some other form of synchronization.

Comment: The problem is that the acquire and release semantics defined by the Standard only allow control over ordering *with respect to `atomic`-qualified objects*.  The ms-volatile semantics guarantee that a write-release will be ordered after *all* preceding operations involving storage--atomic or not--that isn't owned by non-leaked `restrict`-qualified pointers, and likewise a load-acquire will be ordered before *all* following operations involving such storage.

Comment: In some execution environments, given something like `extern int q; extern int volatile * volatile v; ... q=1; q=2; v=&q; while(v) {} q=3;`, the effect of `q=2;` could never be observable, and efficiency could be improved by allowing the compiler to omit it.  In other environments, however, the act of storing `&q` to `v` might make effects of `q=2;` observable, even though the effect of `p=1;` wouldn't be.  I think the authors of C89 expected that people writing implementations for environments where `volatile` operations might make various other actions observable...

Comment: ...would define their `volatile` semantics to accommodate that (or be configurable to do so) rather than requiring the use of non-standard syntax for such purposes.  I'm not sure where people got the idea that the Standard was intended as an invitation for compiler writers to ignore the Spirit of C which the Committee characterized in part as "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done".

Comment: I think the motivation is that class volatile semantics for memory ordering can't be implemented efficiently on weak memory-ordering architectures like ARM. So the C++11 memory model is designed to match that. IOW, by default, no ordering is guaranteed and you must explicitly designate synchronization points. Likewise, any ordering of non-atomics doesn't matter because if it did, it would be a read/write race condition which is automatically UB.

Comment: Programmers using freestanding implementations will usually know things about the target environment that compiler writers won't (and in many cases can't); most of the tasks for which freestanding implementations are used would be impossible without such knowledge.  If a programmer needs to have a compiler perform some stores before a certain "key" store, a programmer should be able to demand such behavior without jumping through hoops, whether or not the compiler writer has any idea of whether it would be useful in the target environment.